# WPF Bind combobox selected item to listview current item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox, bind

Im new to WPF so I must be missing something very obvious.

I have this simple setup:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Student> ClassroomStudents { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        Students.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Name = "John" });
        Students.Add(new Student { ID = 2, Name = "Paul" });
        Students.Add(new Student { ID = 3, Name = "Ringo"});
        Students.Add(new Student { ID = 4, Name = "George" });

        ClassroomStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        ClassroomStudents.Add(Students[0]); //View binds it ok at startup (one way)
        ClassroomStudents.Add(Students[1]); //View binds ut ok at startup (one way)

    }


    public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private void bOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ClassroomStudents[0].Name);

}
```

What I want to achieve is to display the ClassroomStudents collection and add a Combobox on each item which should bind to the collection item.

```
    <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="SortBy" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassroomStudents}" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                             
                            <ComboBox                                    
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Students, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"                                         
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=.,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                                        
                                >
                            </ComboBox>
                            <!--<Label Content="{Binding}"></Label>-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>                   
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <!--OK/CANCEL BUTTONS-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Button x:Name="bOK" IsDefault="True" Margin="10" Width="100" Click="bOK_Click">OK</Button>
        <Button x:Name="bCancel" IsCancel="True" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Click="bCancel_Click">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It binds fine in one way:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZZlz.jpg)

however if I select another Student in the combobox the collection value on the model doesn't change:

```
MessageBox.Show(ClassroomStudents[0].Name); //Always return John
```

I found some answers suggesting to bind to a property (ie ID) but I want to bind to the collection Item (Student).

Thanks,
Rodo.

Comment: Create a property `ChosenStudent` of type `Student` which will contain the selected item. and use it like this `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.ChosenStudent,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"`.

Comment: _"collection value on the model doesn't change"_ -- why should it? changing the selection in the combo box doesn't rearrange the order of the collection, so why would `ClassroomStudents[0]` return a different `Student` object than before? Not even counting the fact that your `ComboBox` control appears to be bound to the `Students` collection, not the `ClassroomStudents` collection. Frankly, it is not at all clear what you expect or want to happen, or why, especially given that you apparently have already ruled out a separate property to bind the `SelectedItem` property to(per previous comment)

Comment: You can't two-way bind the current DataContext, only properties within the context. You should get a warning or error with your binding `{Binding Path=.,Mode=TwoWay}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix I can think of is wrapping your `ClassroomStudents` items in a selection container:

```
public class StudentContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Student Item { get; set; } // TODO: INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

Change the collection and initialization:

```
public ObservableCollection<StudentContainer> ClassroomStudents { get; set; }
// ...
ClassroomStudents.Add(new StudentContainer { Item = Students[0] });
```

Change the XAML

```
<ComboBox                                    
    ItemsSource="{Binding Students, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Item,Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
```

I hope this is enough to give you a starting point. There are some side-issues in your code that are not directly related to your question but might need some attention in order to get the whole thing working.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I needed. Thank you!